# How to rewrite long URL with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

htaccess file with the following:

```
RewriteRule ^home?$ index.php
```

This works great for rewriting the url of my home page. Users are able to post articles on my site so the url for all the various pages are as follow:

```
http://example.com/article.php?id=22
```

Let's pretend there are 1'000 articles how can I rewrite each article to something like this:

```
example.com/articleId/articleTitle
```

For example:

```
example.com/56732/How-to-bake-bread
```

Is it possible to extract the data of an article and use it to rewrite the article's URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking for that:

```
RewriteRule    ^([0-9]+)/(.+)?$    article.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

The first part of the regex ([0-9]+) captures the id in the url and is passed in the value passed in $1, if you wanted to use as well the (.+) part you could get it using the value in $2.